# Returning non-matching records from a merge

Tags: r, merge

I'm merging two data frames, a main data set and a lookup table, based on multiple factor (key) variables, and I'd like to have a quick way of seeing which combinations of these key variables in the main data did not match in the lookup table. Is there an option in the merge function that would allow me to do this? The best I can think of at the moment is to use the all.x=T option and then look at the rows for which one of the vars that I merged in is NA. Surely there must be a better way...

Here's my code, for what it's worth:

```
a.lighting.all.2 <- merge(a.lighting.all.2, a.lookup.by.meas.2,
                          by = c("measure.category", "measure.subcategory",
                                 "measure", "fund.category"))
```

Comment: What is wrong with just using `NA` to figure out which rows didn't match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function for diff-ing two data.frames with identical headers:

```
df.diff <- function(df1, df2) {
   is.dup <- duplicated(rbind(df2, df1))
   is.dup <- tail(is.dup, nrow(df1))
   df1[!is.dup, ]
}
```

So you can run:

```
df.diff(main[by.cols], lookup[by.cols])
```

Comment: Nice. I was hoping for a built-in way of doing this, but this is a nice elegant solution. Is there a good package for doing QC of large data sets, or do most folks just write their own custom QC functions?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see merge doesn't have this option but subsetting by NAs though is pretty quick and easy.

```
df      <- data.frame(cat=c("a","a","b","b"),num=(1:4))
df2     <- data.frame(cat=c("a","a","b","c"),num=(1:4))
mergedf <- merge(df,df2,by="cat",all=TRUE)
mergedf
mergedf [rowSums(is.na(mergedf))>0 ,] # not if you have NAs already before merge
```

you can also do things like this:

```
df2 [ !df2$cat %in% df$cat ,]
```

and for specific rows not merged:

```
df$ID   <- 1:length(df[,1])
df2$ID  <- (length(df[,1])+1):(length(df[,1])+length(df2[,1]))
mergedf <- merge(df,df2,by="cat", all=FALSE)

df2 [!df2$ID %in% mergedf$ID.y ,]
```

with an example of data perhaps someone can help much better

Answer (score 2):

data.table version:

```
library(data.table)
df1      <- data.table(cat=c("a","a","b","b"),num=(1:4))
   cat num
1:   a   1
2:   a   2
3:   b   3
4:   b   4

df2     <- data.table(cat=c("a","a","b","c"),num=(1:4))
   cat num
1:   a   1
2:   a   2
3:   b   3
4:   c   4

df1[!df2, on=.(cat,num)]
   cat num
1:   b   4

df2[!df1, on=.(cat,num)]
   cat num
1:   c   4
```

Alternatively, set the keys, and delete the on in the brackets.

Comment: What if you have columns with different names in the two different DT?